# How can I access to an item in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data=pd.read_csv('E:\\movie_data.csv')
indices=pd.Series(data.index, index=data['movie_title']).drop_duplicates
indices['Avatar']
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwfWY.png)

I've tried to access an element of this series,
But I received this error:

> TypeError
> ----> 3 indices['Avatar']
> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Help us help you - please [edit] your post and format code - see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help

Comment: Can you give us an extract of your data ?

Comment: `drop_duplicates` is a method, not an attribute, use this:
`indices=pd.Series(data.index, index=data['movie_title']).drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call (using the paranthesis) the `drop_duplicates` method to get a DataFrame in return. Try the following code and it should work :

```
data=pd.read_csv('E:\\movie_data.csv')
indices=pd.Series(data.index, index=data['movie_title']).drop_duplicates()
indices['Avatar']
```

For the record, the error message your are having is because you try to use [object subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) (the bracket notation) on the drop_duplicates *method* not on *the result of this method*.